# SQL param corresponding to '*' when php var empty?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have some SQL functions, an HTML/JS form and a PHP script (which calls SQL functions with form parameters). The form just sends two parameters :

- date
- language

If date is empty, no problem, I can get the date of the day by PHP and pass it to my SQL request. But when $language is empty, I want to display results for all languages..

The php part :

```
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : '';
if (empty($date)) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
}
$language = isset($_GET['language']) ? $_GET['language'] : '';
if (empty($language)) {
    $language = '%';
}

$events = retrieve_events_by_type ($DB, $query, $language, $date);
```

My SQL function :

```
function retrieve_events_by_type ($DB, $type, $language, $date) {
    $req = $DB->prepare("SELECT organizer, eventname, eventplace, language, eventdate, eventhour, eventminutes FROM events where eventtype = ? AND language like ? AND eventdate = ?");

    $req -> bindParam(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req -> bindParam(2, $language, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req -> bindParam(3, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req -> execute();

    $events = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $req->closeCursor();

    return ($events);
```

}

Can I get all languages with this SQL function ?  Or am I forced to create other functions for all cases ..?

Thanks.

Comment: To use wildcards use `like` rather than `=` in SQL, and the wildcards are `_` for one character, and `%` for multiple characters.  There is no `*` wildcard.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to create a second function, I don't see how to use 'like' to correspond at all of these languages : 'allemand', 'anglais', 'espagnol', 'francais', 'italien'.

Comment: `Like` works just like `=` if there are no wildcards.  `like 'italian'` is same as `='italian'` but `like 'it%'` matches any word starting with `it`

Comment: I've edited my post, I can use LIKE to correspond at a pattern of a specific language, but for all languages with one only var, is it really possible ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems working with manual SQL query, so probably it's just my php query.  Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Where is `$query`? You also can simplify your PHP file a bit `$date = (!empty($_GET['date'])) ? $_GET['date'] : date("Y-m-d");`

Comment: No problem with $query , it's another var I set before in the script.  thank you, it's more simple like that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your SQL statement to only include the WHERE portions for language and type if the corresponding vars are set:

```
function retrieve_events_by_type ($DB, $type, $language, $date) {
    $sql = "SELECT organizer, eventname, eventplace, language, eventdate, eventhour, eventminutes FROM events WHERE eventdate = :date ";

    $sql .= empty($language) ? "" : " AND language LIKE :language ";
    $sql .= empty($type) ? "" : " AND eventtype LIKE :type ";

    $req = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $req -> bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if (!empty($language)
        $req -> bindParam(':language', $language, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if (!empty($type)
        $req -> bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $req -> execute();

    $events = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $req->closeCursor();

    return ($events);
}
```

EDIT

Changed to named parameters instead of ?, as the index numbers would be different if you only passed two parameters instead of three.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm.  Just I don't understand why there is 2 checks with  `empty`    (  before and after `$req = $DB->prepare($sql); ` )  Is it really required ?